# Google Analytics shows real time event but not real time conversion

Tags: javascript, forms, google-analytics, dom-events, goal-tracking

I can see the real-time event in Google Analtyics, but I never see the conversion (conversion not seen real-time, and not seen in reporting after weeks). I have a listener on the submit button:

```
 document.getElementById('id123-button-send').addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
   // alert ("Hello World!"); 
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-65998846-1', 'auto', 'mytracker'); 
    ga('mytracker.send', 'pageview'); 
    ga('mytracker.send', 'event', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'Request a Free Estimate');
}
```

**My goal setup:**
Custom Event, Type=Event, details:

- Category: Equals to  Forms
- Action:   Equals so  Submit
- Label:    Equals to  Request a Free Estimate
- Value:    Equals to  1

This shows an event in real-time.

- I checked there are no spaces in the goal or js definition
- The form is administered by 3rd party - 123ContactForms
- 123ContactForms allows attachment of js script to form. The JS form is executed, as proof the event is seen as real-time event in Analytics.

Since I see it in Analytics as an event, why would it not also show as a conversion if the goal is set up properly? **What is my next troubleshooting technique?**
Analytics dashboard and external JS code:

[image: analytics dashboard and external JS code]

Goal Definition:

[image: Goal Definition]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your goal has been configured to expect a `value` of 1, but you are not sending that in your event:

```
ga('mytracker.send', 'event', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'Request a Free Estimate');
```

You should either add the value to your event call, or remove it from your goal. Note the fineprint when creating your goal:

> Set one or more conditions. A conversion will be counted if all of the conditions you set are true when an Event is triggered.

This means that you could set as little as the category itself if you want more similar type goals to be captured, or as as much as you want if you want to be very specific about the goal you want to capture.

Comment: That appears to be it. Thank you !

Comment: edit - at least the goal can now be verified when I remove the 1. Still exploring why not seeing real time conversion.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any filters set to exclude your own visits (and hence conversions).

Answer (score 0):

In Google Analytics goal setup:
- I removed the "1" from the Value field. 
- Additionally, I had to set "Use the Event value as the Goal Value for the conversion" to a NO.  
- Then I proceeded to "Assign a proprietary value to the conversion" and set THAT to "1".

Check in the Real Time dashboard to see the event fire, and now I can also see the Real Time conversion.

Answer (score 0):

My case it was slightly different but it seems to be related to this one, actually this post gave the idea of how to solve my problem.

My scenario:

- Goal set up in GA as event
- Event been fired/configured in GTM

I was able to see the conversions in GA Real Time report, but not in Goals Overview report.

What solved my problem was just assigning a `value=1` for the Event value in GTM.

Hope it helps someone facing the same.